# Credit Bootstrap on website

Tags: licensing, mit

I am creating a website using Bootstrap.

Do I need to credit Bootstrap since it has MIT license?
If so, how can I do that?

Comment: What does the license say about it?

Comment: Have you read [the license FAQ for bootstrap?](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/about/license/)